# Postgresql text search with php

Tags: postgresql

Im new to postgresql and php, but i am looking to implement a full text search and am having trouble querying the basic query for text search, I would like to print the result on screen as it would show in postgres itself,  Help would be greatful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Theres a lot of concepts in your question, lets run through it:

First you need to [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createtable.html):

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  fullname TEXT NOT NULL,
  dob DATE,
  bio TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Insert some test data:

```
INSERT INTO person (fullname, dob, bio) VALUES
('Steve Jobs', '1955-02-24', 'Steven Paul "Steve" Jobs...'),
('Tutankhamun', NULL, 'Tutankhamun (alternately spelled...');
```

To make searching faster you should create a full text index on the column you plan to search on:

```
CREATE INDEX person_fts ON person USING gin(to_tsvector('english', bio));
```

In your PHP script you will have to [connect to PostgreSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php):

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=mary");
```

Now you can do a full text search with [pg_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php):

```
$words = "steve jobs";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE to_tsvector(bio) @@ to_tsquery('$words')";
$query = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
if(!$query)
  die("An error occured.\n");
```

If you want to return everthing like you see it in psql then render the records to a [TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp):

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>{$cell}</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: hi, The create Table doesnt work in postgres 8.4, i am getting a syntax error at the bottom bracket ); I find it strange as i can create other tables with the same syntax.

Comment: Fixed. It was just an extra comma.

Comment: Hi, i am getting an error saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-Apache\Php\apache\www\textsearchtest.php on line 4

Comment: About `CREATE INDEX person_fts ON person USING gin(to_tsvector('english', bio));` ...if i want to search even in other fields, not only `bio`, what i have to do? Have i to do `CREATE INDEX` for every field?

Comment: If you want to search within multiple fields you can concatenate their values in the same index like `to_tsvector('english', bio || field2)`. The downside is you can't use the same index to search in *only* `bio` or `field2`. So you will need to create an index for each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn = pg_connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=lamb password=bar');

$search = 'some words';

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT id, text FROM some_table WHERE text ILIKE '%$search%'");
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($array = pg_fetch_all_columns($result) as $value): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $value[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value[1]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: LIKE/ILIKE is not full text search.